# Wie übersetzt man 'fer à gigot' aus dem Französischen?

Tags: single-word-request

Das Gerät sieht so aus:

> [image] [image]

Das abgebildete Gerät wird dazu benutzt Bratenkeulen zu fixieren. Ist also Teil eines Tranchiersets. In Frankreich jedenfalls.

Der französiche Begriff dafür ist *fer à gigot*, also ~ 'Lammkeuleneisen'. Dieses Wort scheint aber nicht zu existieren. Fusseisen sind offensichtlich nur als Fesseln für noch lebende Menschen bekannt.

Wörterbücher, Maschinenübersetzer, Wikipedia scheinen alle nichts dazu zu kennen.

Es verwundert schon, dass deutsche Nachschlagewerke wie auch Händler nur einen Zweizackspieß  samt Messer als komplettes Tranchierset anzusehen scheinen.

Eine kurze Umfrage unter deutschstämmigen Gastronomen ergab nur Kopschütteln und den Kommentar "Noch nie gesehen!"

Gibt es einen etablierten deutschen Begriff für dieses Gerät, wird wenn überhaupt nur der französische Begriff verwendet, oder existiert vielleicht eine passende Neuschöpfung?

Comment: Interessante Frage! Frag doch auch mal noch bei leo.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Begriff scheint *Keulenhalter* zu sein. Jedenfalls wird der von Händlern so verwendet, zum Beispiel hier:

- https://www.zumkochen.at/kochen-backen/spezialgeraete-f-hobbykoeche/keulenhalter
- https://www.tafelblicke.de/800er-Silber-Keulenhalter-MEYEN-CO
- https://www.amazon.de/Claude-Dozorme-2-50-034-55-Keulenhalter-Buchenholz/dp/B003QCJ5GY

Answer (score 3):

In einem Kochbuch von Time Life aus 1981 wird dieser *manche à gigot* mit *Tranchiergriff* ins Deutsche übersetzt.  Klingt nicht so martialisch wie *Keulenhalter*.